# E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "TABLEaccount": syntax error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting this error in my app when I try to write to database
`E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "TABLEaccount": syntax error`

I cant figure it out why? Here is my code for SQLite databse. I am attaching the complete code for database class here

package com.astrolabe.tcpremote1;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.sql.SQLDataException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class accountsDB {

    //private variables
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CTYPE = "c_type";
    public static final String KEY_SNAME = "s_name";
    public static final String KEY_SNUMB = "s_numb";
    public static final String KEY_USRN = "user_name";
    public static final String KEY_PASS = "password";
    public static final String KEY_EMPTY = "empty";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="account.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="accounts";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;

    private DbHelper  ourHelper;
    private final Context  ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase  ourDatabase;

    public long createEntry(String ctype, String siteName, String siteNum, String username, String pass) {

        ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_CTYPE,ctype);
        cv.put(KEY_SNAME,siteName);
        cv.put(KEY_SNUMB,siteNum);
        cv.put(KEY_USRN,username);
        cv.put(KEY_PASS,pass);
        //cv.put(KEY_EMPTY,0);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);
    }

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
         public DbHelper(Context context){
             super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);

         }

         @Override
         public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
             db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE"+ DATABASE_NAME + "(" +
                KEY_ROWID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"
                     + KEY_CTYPE + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
                     +  KEY_SNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
                     +  KEY_SNUMB + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
                     +  KEY_USRN + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
                     +  KEY_PASS + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
                     +  KEY_EMPTY + "INTEGER);"
                );

         }

         @Override
         public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" +DATABASE_TABLE);
             onCreate(db);

         }
     }

    public accountsDB (Context c)
    {
        ourContext= c;
    }
    public accountsDB open() throws SQLException
    {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return  this;
    }
    public  void close()
    {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add whitespace between SQL tokens, e.g. instead of

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE"+ DATABASE_NAME + "(" +
```

change to

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
```

Notice the space after `TABLE`. I've also changed the table name from `account.db` to `accounts`.

This is what caused the exception. But there are other problems, for example in column specifications

```
KEY_ROWID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"
    + KEY_CTYPE + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
    +  KEY_SNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
    +  KEY_SNUMB + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
    +  KEY_USRN + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
    +  KEY_PASS + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
    +  KEY_EMPTY + "INTEGER);"
```

you need spaces between column names and datatypes and a comma `,` after each column spec:

```
KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
    + KEY_CTYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
    +  KEY_SNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
    +  KEY_SNUMB + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
    +  KEY_USRN + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
    +  KEY_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
    +  KEY_EMPTY + " INTEGER);"
```

In addition there's similar whitespace issue in `onUpgrade()`:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" +DATABASE_TABLE);
```

should be

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DATABASE_TABLE);
```

For easier debugging on your own, have a look at the exception stacktrace to find the exact line of code where the exception occurred.

Comment: @dmsherazi Note that there should be `DATABASE_TABLE` not `DATABASE_NAME` in the table creation sql.

Comment: @dmsherazi Missing `,` comma after the first column

Comment: yeah i just figured out that , Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Check your code-

```
public class accountsDB {

    //private variables
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CTYPE = "c_type";
    public static final String KEY_SNAME = "s_name";
    public static final String KEY_SNUMB = "s_numb";
    public static final String KEY_USRN = "user_name";
    public static final String KEY_PASS = "password";
    public static final String KEY_EMPTY = "empty";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="account.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="accounts";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;

    private DbHelper  ourHelper;
    private final Context  ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase  ourDatabase;

    public long createEntry(String ctype, String siteName, String siteNum, String username, String pass) {


        ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_CTYPE,ctype);
        cv.put(KEY_SNAME,siteName);
        cv.put(KEY_SNUMB,siteNum);
        cv.put(KEY_USRN,username);
        cv.put(KEY_PASS,pass);
        //cv.put(KEY_EMPTY,0);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);
    }

    private class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
         public DbHelper(Context context){
             super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);

         }

         @Override
         public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
             String q="CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                     + KEY_CTYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                     +  KEY_SNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                     +  KEY_SNUMB + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                     +  KEY_USRN + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                     +  KEY_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                     +  KEY_EMPTY + " INTEGER);";

             Log.e("","ssssssssss: "+ q);


             db.execSQL(q);

         }

         @Override
         public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" +DATABASE_TABLE);
             onCreate(db);

         }
     }

    public accountsDB (Context c)
    {
        ourContext= c;
    }
    public accountsDB open() throws SQLException
    {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return  this;
    }
    public  void close()
    {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

  }
```

Comment: after chnaging to this it says `E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) unknown database account`

Comment: now check it is working now. "Create table table name" not db name.  also a comma was missing and off-course white spaces too.